# Use a list comprehension to select all three letter words from a list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
words = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'.split()
print words
```

That's the list. I've been trying out some code to get the 3 letter words but no luck? This is what I had so far below to get the three letter words:

```
for word in words:
    wordsByLength[ len(word) ].append( word )
```

but I think I may be going the wrong way about it.

Comment: `threeletterwords = [word for word in words if len(word)==3]`

Comment: @khelwood: are you familiar with the difference between answers and comments?

Comment: @DSM Yes, but I thought it was too trivial to bother writing a complete answer for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a comprehension to iterate over the list you made, and then check the length as you go:

```
three_letters = [word for word in words if len(word) == 3]
```

Comment: Thank-you so much :) im new too python, it worked:) just had to add the print three_letters at the end it worked perfect

Comment: @TheAfsan Great, glad I could help. When it allows you, consider accepting my answer to indicate that your problem is solved, thanks :).

Comment: im just waiting for the 5 mins to end, once again thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
len_three = []

for i in words:
    if len(i) == 3:
        len_three.append(i)

print len_three # ['The', 'fox', 'the', 'dog']
```

Comment: your code seems functional, however kindly notice the Original Post was asking for a **"list comprehension"** approach to the solution. You may also notice, that khelwood has posted a nice piece of such a code, to inspire your further thoughts. Enjoy both python & StackOverflow Community

Comment: This is not a better answer than @AlexThorntons.  More code, appending each item to a list one at a time...